# Mouse pointer doesn't move, but mouse does respond to clicks. Fully works only temporarily in BIOS setup screen

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I'm having a very weird issue with my mouse. Suddenly, in the middle of a web browsing session, it stopped responding to movement. The computer was fully responsive, and the mouse continued to allow me to click, right-click and scroll, but the cursor wouldn't move.

The mouse is wired, and is lit up ok, and the sensor is clean (it's a Cyborg RAT 5, and I'm running Windows 7 64-bit).

I've tried plugging it into different USB ports, reinstalled the drivers, booted into safe mode, but the same problem persists. Just now I tried attaching it to a different computer and got the same symptoms immediately, so I guess that suggests the mouse hardware is screwy...

To back that up, a different mouse works fine.

Interestingly, when I restarted I jumped into the BIOS setup and there the mouse worked perfectly for about 30 seconds, after which it started to slow down until eventually it was completely stationary no matter how much I moved it.

I think that covers all the steps I've taken - at this point I'm pretty much stumped as to whether the mouse is fixable or just a paperweight at this stage. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the mouse _always_ briefly work in the BIOS screen or did that only happen once?

Comment: Get a new mouse.................